# Proving that $2^x - x^4$ is an increasing function on the domain $[16,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

On the surface, this one seems simple and obvious.

Yet, I am scratching my head how to prove that for $x \ge 16$, $2^x - x^4$ is an increasing function.

To do this, I need to show that the derivative is greater than $0$ for $x \ge 16$.

The derivative of $2^x - x^4$ is:

$$2^x\log(2)-4x^3$$

which isn't much better than the original equation.

What is the simplest way to complete this argument?

Comment: You mean $[16,\infty)$ for the domain, right?

Comment: Yes.  I will make the correction.  Thanks!

Comment: It is even true for $x\geq 14$.  If you enjoy Lambert function, you could have a lot of fun.

Comment: Thanks!  :-)  I'll read up on Lambert functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continue taking derivatives until the polynomial part vanishes:

$$ f''(x) = 2^x\log(2)^2 - 12x^2 \\
f^{(3)}(x) = 2^x\log(2)^3 - 24x \\
f^{(4)}(x) = 2^x\log(2)^4 - 24 \\
f^{(5)}(x) = 2^x\log(2)^5 $$

The fifth derivative is positive everywhere, and by direct computation each of the lower derivatives are at least positive at $x=16$. Therefore each of them (working backwards from "fifth") must be positive everywhere to the right of $x=16$. In particular this holds for the first derivative.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I suspected that the solution was staring me straight in the face.